# Internet connection through Bluetooth PAN profile?

Tags: networking, bluetooth, 9.04

Is there any guide to get Internet connection through Bluetooth PAN profile in Ubuntu? I am using ubuntu 9.04.

Comment: Read [this](http://blog.myfenris.net/2009/01/01/internet-sharing-via-bluetooth-pan-with-wm-61-pro-ubuntu/),it may help you but not sure..

Comment: This question seems abandoned, there is not further information or activity added to it for several months. I am flagging this to be closed by a moderator. If you think this issue is still affecting you you can flag a moderator to re-open it.

Answer (score 3):

Does this howto help?

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=598890

Comment: This is quite old, there should be some newer guide somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about 904 but natty supports connection through bluetooth PAN out of the box via NetworkManager. You have to pair the mobile device with your computer using the bluetooth-application. After that the bluetooth device can be selected in the nm-applet as a network device.  Maybe it's just as simple with 9.04.